# ggplot with several lines (development over time)

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I would like to create a ggplot with several lines. However the output does not look like I want it. It looks like the points are marked vertically. However I want to link the values of each period that I see the time development (more like horizontally).

I have a dataset with a date (mostly monthly but not always), a column which I want to display as different lines (5 lines 0-4) named "color", and the values. It looks like this:

```
 head(df)
        date color     value
1 2007-01-01     0 0.5071167
2 2007-02-01     0 0.5071167
3 2007-03-01     0 0.5071167
4 2007-04-01     0 0.5071167
5 2007-05-01     0 0.7292619
6 2007-06-01     0 0.5071167
```

I tried to make a ggplot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= date, y = value, color = color)) + geom_line()
```

[image: the following plot was created]

however I would prefer a plot which shows one clear line per color (makes 5 lines)such that it is possible to see how it develops over time. more like this but with 5 lines:
[image: how the plot should look like]

I would be glad I somewone could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your plot appears this way because the column `color` is numeric, so it is being treated as a continuous variable by ggplot. This means that ggplot thinks you want all the observations to be in the same group. When it sees 5 different variables with the same `date`, it draws a vertical line connecting them, which is obviously not what you want. You need to let ggplot know that you intend `color` to be a *categorical* variable rather than a continuous variable.

If you convert `color` to a factor, the plot will split the observations into five groups according to color and plot them the way you want. You can either convert the number within the data frame, or do it directly in the aesthetic:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= date, y = value, color = as.factor(color))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(colour = "color")
```

You get this:
[image]

---

**Data used**

```
set.seed(69)
df <- data.frame(date = rep(as.POSIXct("2007-01-01") + lubridate::days(1:3650), 5),
                 color = rep(0:4, each = 3650),
                 value = c(cumsum(rnorm(3650)), cumsum(rnorm(3650)),  cumsum(rnorm(3650)),
                           cumsum(rnorm(3650)), cumsum(rnorm(3650))))
```

Comment: thank you very much! yes I did in fact just need to change the class of my color variable :)